# SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declaration are not supported in strict mode

Tags: webpack, babeljs, nuxt.js

Getting the above mentioned syntax error on **Nuxt 1.4** project.

This is happening on Safari 9, same is working fine on Chrome.

I searched on SO and found the issue due to the browser compatibility issue of ES6 code but not able to find a proper solution to the problem (Nuxt project).

The website should work on the old versions of the browser too.

Below are the nuxt.config.js and package.json file details

> 1. nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** Run ESLint on save
    */
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    },
    vendor: ['babel-polyfill']
  }
}
```

> 2. package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "nuxt": "^1.4.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.6.5",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.4.2",
    "vue-smooth-scroll": "^1.0.13",
    "vue-tabs-component": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-youtube-embed": "^2.1.3",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^0.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "eslint": "^4.17.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0-beta.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^11.6.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use Babel to compile your code down to regular es5 or es6 code, depending on the compatibility you're looking for.

In Nuxt, there is a `babel` option you can use in your `nuxt.config.js` that takes care of the compiling for you.
Have a look at the documentation for the `babel` option here: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#babel

If you're getting the error from inside Nuxt, you should look into upgrading to `nuxt-edge` for legacy support.